# Adding variables in bash

Tags: bash, variables, floating-point

I am trying to assign 2 variables floating values and then trying to store the sum in third variable but I get an error.

```
#!/bin/bash
x=0.1
y=1000.0
z=$((x+y))

echo $z
```

output is: xyz.sh: 6: xyz.sh: Illegal number: 0.1

I am unable to understand what is going wrong.

I want z to be = 1000.01

Answer (score 3):

BASH doesn't support floating point arithmetic. Use `bc` command instead:

```
z=$(bc -l <<< "$x + $y")
echo "$z"
1000.1
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried using bc and it worked out.

#!/bin/bash

    x=0.1
    y=1000.0

    z= echo "$x+$y"|bc
    echo "$z"

Comment: I got stuck again. its actually not storing value in z but just printing it because i used

z= echo "$x+$y"|bc

when I used

z=$(bc -l <<< "$x + $y")

it says redirectionunexpected

Comment: using that syntax gives me a syntax error which say                     xyz.sh: 6: xyz.sh: Syntax error: redirection unexpected

Comment: Can you show you full script by editing the question. Make sure you are using bash not sh